# How to make this WordPress Plugin more elegant and faster?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I have written the following Plugin, which adds fields to the Media/Attachment Entries and returns all information in one Shortcode. This solution works, however, is pretty slow the more entries available.

I know that the problem lies in the while loop. However, I included the entire code in order to see what I'm trying to achieve:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Are you ok?' );
/** ----- ADD FIELDS IN MEDIA LIBRARY ----- **/
function additionalMediaFields( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['copyright_author'] = array(
        'label' => '&copy; Autor',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'copyright_author', true ),            
    );
    $form_fields['copyright_description'] = array(
        'label' => '&copy; Beschreibung',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'copyright_description', true ),           
    );
    $form_fields['copyright_website'] = array(
        'label' => '&copy; Website',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'copyright_website', true ),           
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'additionalMediaFields', 10, 2 );

function storeAdditionalMediaFields( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['copyright_author'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'copyright_author', $attachment['copyright_author'] );
    if( isset( $attachment['copyright_description'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'copyright_description', $attachment['copyright_description'] );
    if( isset( $attachment['copyright_website'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'copyright_website', $attachment['copyright_website'] );
    return $post;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'storeAdditionalMediaFields', 10, 2 );

/** ----- SHOW THEM IN ONE SHORTCODE ----- **/
function listAllCopyrightInformation ($atts, $content = null) {

    $i = 1;
    while ( $i<=20000 ) {
        $copyrightAuthor = get_post_meta($i, 'copyright_author', true );
        $copyrightDescription = get_post_meta($i, 'copyright_description', true );
        $copyrightWebsite = get_post_meta($i, 'copyright_website', true );

        if ( !empty($copyrightAuthor)) {
            if( !empty($copyrightDescription)) {
                $CopyrightEntries .= $copyrightDescription . ': ';
            }
            $CopyrightEntries .= '&copy; ';
            $CopyrightEntries .= $copyrightAuthor;
            if( !empty($copyrightWebsite)) {
                $CopyrightEntries .= ' / <a href="https://' . get_post_meta($i, 'copyright_website', true) . '" target="_blank">' . get_post_meta($i, 'copyright_website', true) . '</a> || ';
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $CopyrightReturn = substr($CopyrightEntries, 0, -8);
    return $CopyrightReturn;
}

add_shortcode("show-all-copyrights", "listAllCopyrightInformation");
```

Thanks in advance. I appreciate your effort!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it's working code it probably wants to be on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: what is the 20000 and why?